# Setting root directory in a development environment

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I have a linux server that I do all of my web development on.  I cant find an example of a virtual host.

I need a way to set virtual hosts (i think) so that even when i am running   http://dev.example.com/blah i need that URL to be treated as a different site.

I know that i cannot use sub domains because to access the server I have to navigate through a sub domain.

If you need any clarifications please ask.

Answer (score 0):

Virtual hosts are set using a `<VirtualHost>` section in apache configuration file(s) generally being `httpd.conf`,`apache2.conf`.It looks like

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dev.example.com
    ServerName dev.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

You can change `DocumentRoot` as per your convenience.

In few versions of distros such different sections of main trivial configuration file `httpd.conf` are segregated to separate files.

For example apache2 on latest ubuntu has separate files per virtual host located at `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/`

You may find `000-default` already in this directory which sets the default host(localhost)
You may copy it and start editing to define a new virtual host.With above snippet you will be configuring new host. Key point is setting `DocumentRoot` to a different directory for `dev.example.com` to configure as a different site.
I assume your dev machine is able to resolve what is set for `ServerName` else you may want to configure it too in `/etc/hosts` on debian based linux.

Comment: But would it be possible to get a virtual host at http://dev.example.com/foo? even though that is technically a directory extension?

Comment: Yes that's possible with `mod_rewrite`.Have a look at this [link](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/mass.html). You simply need a custom `RewriteRule`